# Using a script instead of defining a huge DNS zone

Tags: cloud-service, dns, cloud

I am evaluating how to implement a solution similar to the [approach of plex](https://blog.filippo.io/how-plex-is-doing-https-for-all-its-users/) for embedded devices.

This solution requires defining 2^32 record for each device, creating a monster zone that easily exceeeds 10^15 entries. This is almost impossibile to deal with.

I am wondering if DNS software can offer the possibility of using a scirpt to determine the lookup result instead of having di provide all the possible entries of zone, but I am not able to find such a software.

Do you know any DNS software that allows using scripts to perform the lookup in a zone? Is there any cloud provider that offers a service based on any of the programs?

Comment: Wow, what an amazing question! Sad than I can give only a single up. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [powerdns](https://www.powerdns.com). It is a DNS server, where the zones are served not from text files (or from a db file) as in bind, instead they are served from configurable backends. These are mostly databases (i.e. to serve zones from mysql/postgresql/anything), but they can be also scripts. Doing it with a script, essentially we can do the analog of (f)cgi scripting, but for serving DNS requests.

Between the backends, I see two options:

1. [PostgreSQL](https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/backends/postgresql.html). In theory, it is for serving the zone from postgresql tables, however postgres has very nice options for scripting/triggers with its procedural language, [plpgsql](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/pgSQL). You can try to make some trigger or dynamical view functionality of it, to generate the zone run-time.
2. (This is imho the best) [Pipe](https://doc.powerdns.com/authoritative/backends/pipe.html):

> The PipeBackend allows for easy dynamic resolution based on a ‘Coprocess’ which can be written in any programming language that can read a question on standard input and answer on standard output.

If you want to make it really fast, you could also set up a caching bind9 before the powerdns backend.

<sub>I would also suggest to not get examples from control panels. None of them is very useful. This 2^32 monster-zone is probably one of the top 10 worst ideas I've met on the whole SE.</sub>